# How to track the download complete time of a file at server ?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, download

I want to log the time at the  web server  when a download starts and completes at client machine ? Is this possible ? I am using IIS 7. I tried to utilize this http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/
along with a PHP script but not successful. Please suggest a proper procedure for this..

Thanks...

Comment: Did you have any tests ? any tries, do you have the code that make the download of a file ?

Comment: Its just a hyperlink in a page. When a user clicks on the hyperlink, file will be downloaded.

Comment: Try to make a handler that sent the file, and measure the start and the end of this one inside the handler

Comment: could you please elaborate ? Or  plz provide me some links..